# XSD 1.1: use assertion to restrict elements based on parent attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, schema, assertion

Given the XML

```
<test type="a">
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
</test>
```

I would like to do something as simple as using an XSD assertion to forbid the use of, say, the element "foo" if @type is something other than "a". I've tried an assertion in the following schema:

```
<xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo"/>
            <xs:element name="bar"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:Name">
                    <xs:enumeration value="a"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="b"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:assert test="not(@type='b' and exists(foo))"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But this does not work. I am using Oxygen which in turn uses the Saxon validator, and the assertion always fails. Assertions work otherwise (asserting `test="@type='b'"` correctly rejects the above XML snippet) but for some reason I can't test for the existence of a child element to `test`. I've also tried `exists(./foo)` and `count(foo) gt 0` to no avail.

Have I misunderstood something about the xpath syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thank you for providing a minimum working example.  But I'm unable to replicate the problem:  for me, Oxygen 15.2 accepts the XML document you give and rejects a similar document with `type='b'`, whether I set the validator to Saxon or Xerces.  So this looks like a ghost problem.  I have sometimes found myself confused by old error-message buffers (since Oxygen does not magically notice when they are no longer current).  So if it were me, I'd advise restarting Oxygen or otherwise making sure all buffers and caches are current.

Comment: I wonder if there are namespaces involved? If element foo is in a namespace, then you need to adjust the XPath expression accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! It was indeed a namespace issue, so thank you Michael! I had assumed that since the assertion operates on a subtree of the test element, all the child elements would be "local variables". But adding the correct namespace did the trick!